# Blue-ish band on a MacBook Pro screen

Tags: display, screen

I'm on a MacBook Pro 15-inch, 2018. I have just realized that there's a dark blue band on the bottom right of the screen. You can see it in this photo:

[image]

I'm quite sure that it is a display problem, but I'd like to ask if there's something that I can do to mitigate that problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there’s nothing you can do to address this other than take it in for service.

It could be a loose or damaged flex cable or it could be a faulty panel that needs to be replaced.  Either way, it’s a physical issue that can’t be addressed other than a physical repair.